# Vmplayer hosted by Ubuntu 14.04 installed Win 10 cannot use internet connection,

Tags: 14.04, networking, vmware

Hiyo,

I have been seeking de solution as title, yet there is no a straight-forward right answer.,
so I publish it. If I get some miss, please refer it to me.

Based on Ubuntu 14.04 OS installed  VMplayer with windows 10, the Win10 shows the unidentified connection on the internet access, but Ubuntu runs internet connection properly by either cable or wifi.

However, I have tried to switch different way for vm-Win 10 connecting config, such as NAT, Bridged, Host-only, and re-installed vmware tools several times. They all remain the same cause of unidentified connection.

Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: vmware shows that the virtual network cars is ok? And what is the output of the `ip addr`?